# AWS Certificate Manager failed validation due to a Certificate Authority Authentication error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-acm

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills, because I've completed this process before and my configuration seems to match [AWS' docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-troubleshoot-caa-errors/). But, every time I request a new certificate, I get this error message (usually less than a minute after making the request):

> The status of this certificate request is "Failed". One or more domain names have failed validation due to a Certificate Authority Authentication (CAA) error. [Learn more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/acm/troubleshoot-caa).

I've [requested](https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home) a public certificate with two domain names: "mydomain.us" and "*.mydomain.us". I chose email validation and did not apply any tags. I copied the CNAME record (_1234567890etc.mydomain.us.) into NameCheap and added a CAA record as well.

```
CAA Record @ 0 issue "amazon.com" Automatic
```

NameCheap (domain registrar):
[image: DNS Config on NameCheap]

Immediately after request:
[image: ACM during validation]

After validation fails:
[image: ACM failed]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: More screenshots

Comment: At what point are you getting that message? What is the domain name you're trying to use? Knowing the domain name makes helping you easier in some cases. Screenshots might also be useful. Suggest editing your post rather than using comments.

Comment: How / when does the status go from "pending" to "failed". Please try to add all the steps or events to your question.

Comment: There's no step in between, the content of the page simply updates. As I said, this is usually less than a minute after making the request.

Comment: I'd have to do the research to try to work this out, same as you. If you don't get an answer get AWS Support for a month, they're pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and discovered the answer for me this post: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/acm-troubleshoot-caa-errors. Our CAA record for the root domain has the `issuewild ";"` tag which blocks wildcard certificates from being issued.